# A reference for ring examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm currently reading "Introduction to Ring Theory" by Paul Cohn

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852332069/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1517544148&sr=8-3&keywords=cohn+ring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852332069)

As I'm working through it, I'm realizing I'm really deficient in having examples of various properties at the ready, and it makes it hard to establish a mental picture of what's happening as I read - for instance, a theorem may have the hypotheses "Let $R$ be a simple ring" or "Let $R$ be an Artinian ring" - and I have difficulty conjuring examples to use as I try to understand what the theorem is saying. This is especially difficult because most of the rings that come to mind are fields or at least commutative, and these cases tend to trivialize many of the theorems in the book.

How does one start building up a collection of rings with various properties to use as examples when those properties are invoked? Are there references that exist for this already?

EDIT: I've decided to include some of my background - I'm an undergraduate student (nearly graduated) in math, with a relatively heavy algebra background - I've taken 4 semesters of algebra classes, two of which were at the graduate level. I'm familiar with introductory modern algebra, I'm just lacking in the "canonical example of structure X with property P" department.

Comment: For commutative rings, the following book would qualify: 
$$$$
Hutchins -- Examples of Commutative Rings (1984)
$$$$

Comment: @quasi Hmm, nice! I had never heard of that book! Definitely going to check it out...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually you just accumulate examples as you go. You find them while reading, while learning from on teachers , and gradually gain experience finding your own.

Since I also sought to learn lots of examples, I began a website, the [Database of ring theory](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com)  to facilitate this.

The name aspires to more, but for now its strength is as a database of examples of rings with identity.

A great way to cement an example in memory is to tie it with some theorem, or surprising property it has.  For example, the [endomorphism ring of a countable infinite dimensional vector space](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/15/) contains elements such that $ab=1$ and $ba\neq1$, and it is isomorphic to all square matrix rings over itself.

Comment: Glancing at your website now, this seems like an excellent resource! Can you filter rings by multiple properties?

Comment: @MightyTyGuy sure, did you find the [search page](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/)?

Comment: Your database looks great! I love it.

Comment: @Orat thanks! I hope people learn a lot from it and get a lot of use out of it. And I hope always to get recommendations for additions...

Comment: What introductory ring theory book would you recommend to undergrad?

Comment: @nevergraduating It depends on the level of the undergrad - are they familiar with abstract algebra and looking to get into deeper ring theory, or is modern algebra completely unknown to them?

Comment: Nice site! There goes my evening.

Comment: @MightyTyGuy Chinese remainder theorem for rings is as far as (I) got. Basic sophomore group theory, Sylow theorems, isomorphism theorems etc.

Comment: @nevergraduating [This](https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Abstract-Algebra-P-Bhattacharya/dp/0521466296/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1517588782&sr=8-1&keywords=basic+abstract+algebra+jain&dpID=41mXy8JmUEL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch) was my first real algebra book. I've seen a lot of other introductory titles thrown around, but I haven't used many of them. To get through quals, I crossreferenced Isaacs' *Graduate algebra*, Hungerford, Dummit & Foote, and Grillet's *Abstract algebra*, plus a few other random titles.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying